# Splitting one Array into many Array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, split

I'm in need of splitting of the single array into multiple array for some report generating purpose.

I have an array like this which I have given below.

```
Array
(
    [blah_1] => 1
    [blahblah_1] => 31
    [blahblahblah_1] => 25
    [blah_3] => 1
    [blahblah_3] => 3
    [blahblahblah_3] => 5
    [blah_10] => 1
    [blahblah_10] => 10
    [blahblahblah_10] => 2
)
```

I want to split the above to,

```
Array
(
    [blah_1] => 1
    [blahblah_1] => 31
    [blahblahblah_1] => 25
)

Array
(
    [blah_3] => 1
    [blahblah_3] => 3
    [blahblahblah_3] => 5
)

Array
(
    [blah_10] => 1
    [blahblah_10] => 10
    [blahblahblah_10] => 2
)
```

How can I do this in PHP ??

Comment: have you tried array_chunk? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: Do all of the  keys for each group _always_ exist, or are the number of keys per group dynamic and determined only by the `_n` on the end?

Comment: Ya the groups are dynamic, sometimes it comes & sometimes it doesn't. I tried, Array_chunk & array_slice, both doesn't satisfy my need.
This is purely determined by `_n`.

Comment: Added a  downvote , because  you didn't add an exact information in the question,  that you would like to  group by "_n" . If you don't tell me what you exactly need, we can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$oldarray=array('blah_1'=>1,'blahblah_1'=>31,'blahblahblah_1'=>25,
'blah_3'=>1,'blahblah_3'=>3,'blahblahblah_3'=>5,
'blah_10'=>1,'blahblah_10'=>10,'blahblahblah_10'=>2
)
$newarray=array();

foreach ($oldarray as $key=>$val) { //Loops through each element in your original array

    $parts=array_reverse(explode('_',$key)); //Splits the key around _ and reverses
    $newarray[$parts[0]][$key]=$val; //Gets the first part (the number) and adds the
    //value to a new array based on this number.

}
```

The output will be:

```
Array (
    [1]=>Array
    (
        [blah_1] => 1
        [blahblah_1] => 31
        [blahblahblah_1] => 25
    )

    [3]=>Array
    (
        [blah_3] => 1
        [blahblah_3] => 3
        [blahblahblah_3] => 5
    )

    [10]=>Array
    (
        [blah_10] => 1
        [blahblah_10] => 10
        [blahblahblah_10] => 2
    )
)
```

Comment: I got the array like this, ``

Comment: I just fixed a few mismatched variables in the code I wrote - the reply box isn't great for formatting :L Should work fine now.

Comment: I got the array like what you have shown, but how do I get how I have shown above?
or is there anyway that I can use it in while loop ? coz now the page loads, doesn't stops, I think infinite loop.

Comment: The only reason an infinite loop would be occuring is if the `$oldarray` value was being written to as the loop happened.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php). Example:

```
<?php
   $chunks = array_chunk($yourarray, 3);
   print_r($chunks);
?>
```

Comment: Will work _if_ the keys are always grouped in the same quantities.  Fails if, for example `[blahblah_3]` doesn't exist

Comment: He didn't mention that the keys must be grouped though.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_chunk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

i.e

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
var_dump(array_chunk($a, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

but take a look at this example:

```
    <?php
        $input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");


       print_r(array_slice($input, 2, -1));
       print_r(array_slice($input, 2, -1, true));
?>
```

will result in this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => c
    [1] => d
)
Array
(
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
array_chunk ( array $input , int $size);
```

Comment: I can create a  whole sentence for this response, I didn't feel it's necessary.